# iOS Simulator Not Recognizing Gestures

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am adding a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and a UITapGestureRecognizer to a view in a view controller's viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardSwipe:)]];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardTap:)]];
    }
- (void)cardSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //get the card. set faceUp to false.
    CGPoint location =  [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    NSIndexPath *cellIndex = [self.cardCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
    if(cellIndex){
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self collectionView:self.cardCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:cellIndex];
        if(cell && [cell isKindOfClass:[CardCollectionViewCell class]]){
            [[((CardCollectionViewCell *)cell) cardView] handleCardSwipe];
        }
    }
}
- (void)cardTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //get the card. set faceUp to false.
    CGPoint location =  [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    NSIndexPath *cellIndex = [self.cardCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
    if(cellIndex){
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self collectionView:self.cardCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:cellIndex];
        if(cell && [cell isKindOfClass:[CardCollectionViewCell class]]){
            [[((CardCollectionViewCell *)cell) cardView] handleCardSwipe];
        }
    }
}
```

In case this is relevant: The view contains a UICollectionView.

The taps and swipes are not getting recognized. Is there something obvious that I am missing?
Thanks.

Comment: have you checked wether these methods are called or not...?

Comment: Please read the docs for `UIGestureRecognizer`. Specifically the part about checking the gesture recognizer's `state` property in the action method.

Comment: If your collection view covers the whole `self.view` then the gesture recognizers for `self.view` will probably never get any events since the collection view will handle them all.

Comment: did you set UIGestureRecognizerDelegate for the viewcontroller?

Comment: @AhmedZ. The methods are not getting called. I set breakpoints and tried the swipes and taps in the simulator, the breakpoints don't get triggered.

Comment: @rmaddy I have an outlet in the controller that references the UICollectionView. And I have tried adding the gesture recognizers to the UICollectionView reference instead of self.view in viewDidLoad. Still the gestures are not recognized. Btw, does anyone know why the question has been -1ed?

Comment: @sugan.s No I did not set the delegate. From the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html it seems it is not strictly needed. I removed one of the gestures (swipe) to remove the possibility of the gestures interfering with each other, the tap gesture was still not recognized.

Comment: jsut check any other view placed above self.view  @septerr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the view was not responding to any gestures - scrolling, taps on buttons or the swipe actions. I deleted generated folders from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator / 6.1/Applications` and `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, reset the simulator settings (from `iOS Simulator` > `Reset Contents and Settings`), did a clean in xcode (Product > Clean) and ran the app again. The gestures are now recognized. I am not sure which of the above fixed the problem...it is possible that simply resetting the simulator's contents and settings would have been enough.

Comment: This is a legit issue that has nothing to do with code, although I can't contribute an explanation as to the cause. When I encountered it, all I did was to reset the simulator and redeploy the app and things started working again.

Comment: I am having this problem after doing a simulator reset, but only on the iPhone 6 simulator.

Answer (score 11):

**Restarting the simulator** worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select `Show Device Bezels`:

```
Goto simulator > Window > Enable Show Device Bezels
```

[image]

Enjoy your swipe to back gesture.

Answer (score 0):

add this method to your viewcontroller so your UICollectionView doesn't block other gestures

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> protocol to the controller's interface, set self as the tap gesture recognizer's delegate and added the method above. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have already enabled Device Bezels from Window panel but still can't use swipe to go back gesture. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510787/5969121).

All you need to do is restart the simulator and try to swipe from the real edge of the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are pressing the trackpad to initiate the gesture.  Pasted from the Apple Dev Forums.

This is what I was doing when it DID NOT work:

- Press the "Option" key
- See the two circles
- Move the mouse back and forth

This is what I was doing when it DID work:

- Press the "Option" key
- See the two circles
- Click the mouse button (to simulate touching the screen)
- Move the mouse back and forth

Answer (score -5):

First you Need To Add UITapGestureRecognizer Delegate method To .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImgView:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        doubleTap.delegate = self;

- (void)doubleTapImgView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
   //Do What you want Here
}
```

Comment: You do not need to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. It is optional. You only set it up if you need to implement the delegate methods. And there is no such thing as `UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate`.