# iOS13 pop viewcontroller by swipe (screen edge) not working

Tags: ios13

Having normal `UINavigationController` stack with some `UIViewController` pushed, I cannot use (screen edge) swiping gesture to go back to root view controller. No custom navBar, no custom back button.

Is anything changed related to using this 'back' swipe gesture? I know that there is a lot new about presenting modals as cards and their dismissal. But I am having troubles with standard `pushViewController:animated:`.

Building the same project against iOS12 works perfectly fine.

Comment: Seems like that this is also the case for Settings app on simulator. So this issue could be system wide.

Comment: Can you please explain about Settings app? As i am getting in device too.

Comment: @Hindu When I open Settings app on the simulator I am not able to swipe back as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Simulator Not Recognizing Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683688/ios-simulator-not-recognizing-gestures)

Comment: same for me, even not working with Settings app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `iOS13` you have to use simulator with bezels. So turning on **Window > Show device bezels** provide you with swipe back in simulator. Oh dear.

Comment: That's crazy, but still not working for me even with enabled bezels. Any ideas? Not working also in the system apps like Settings etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Viktor Kucera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100915/5969121) answer didn't help me until I restarted the simulator and tried to swipe from the real edge of the simulator.

**Start swiping right from the bezels**, not in the UIViewController.

[image]